# Android firebase modifying list with in runTransaction

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have very simple transactional code:

```
postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                Post post = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
                if (post == null) {
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                if(null == post.getLikes())
                    post.setLikes(new ArrayList<String>());

                String currentUserId = // get id

                if (post.getLikes().contains(currentUserId)) {
                    // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                    post.setLikeCounts(post.getLikeCounts() - 1);
                    post.getLikes().remove(currentUserId);

                } else {
                    // Star the post and add self to stars
                    post.setLikeCounts(post.getLikeCounts() + 1);
                    post.getLikes().add(currentUserId);

                }

                // Set value and report transaction success
                mutableData.setValue(post);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Transaction completed
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
            }
        });
```

But am seeing weird behavior here adding a string to the `likes` list is not modifying the list at all:

```
post.getLikes().add(currentUserId);
```

I even stopped debugger and tried to add hardcoded values to the list but still no change.

Update (Post class):

---

```
package com.dsharew.aradavibes.model;

import com.dsharew.aradavibes.providers.LocalDataProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by dsharew on 6/1/17.
 */

public class Post extends Entity{

    public static final String FIELD_AUTHOR_ID = "authorId";
    public static final String FIELD_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String FIELD_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String FIELD_POST_IMAGE_IDS = "postImageIds";
    public static final String FIELD_POST_VIDEO_IDS = "postVideoIds";

    User author;
    String title;
    String description;
    String authorId;

    List<String> postImageIds;
    List<String> postVideoIds;

    List<PostImage> postImages;
    List<PostVideo> postVideos;

    int likeCounts;
    List<String> likes;

    int viewCounts;
    List<String>views;

    public Post(){

    }

    public Post(String title, String description, List<String> postImageIds, List<String> postVideoIds){

        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.postImageIds = postImageIds;
        this.postVideoIds = postVideoIds;

    }

    public List<String> getPostImageIds() {
        return postImageIds;
    }

    public void setPostImageIds(List<String> postImageIds) {
        this.postImageIds = postImageIds;
    }

    public List<String> getPostVideoIds() {
        return postVideoIds;
    }

    public void setPostVideoIds(List<String> postVideoIds) {
        this.postVideoIds = postVideoIds;
    }

    @Exclude
    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthorId() {
        return authorId;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(String authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Exclude
    public List<PostImage> getPostImages() {
        return postImages;
    }

    public void setPostImages(List<PostImage> postImages) {
        this.postImages = postImages;
    }

    public int getLikeCounts() {
        return likeCounts;
    }

    public void setLikeCounts(int likeCounts) {
        this.likeCounts = likeCounts;
    }

    public List<String> getLikes() {

        if(null == likes) return new ArrayList<String>();

        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(List<String> likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    @Exclude
    public List<PostVideo> getPostVideos() {

        if(null == postVideos)
            postVideos = new ArrayList<PostVideo>();

        return postVideos;
    }

    public int getViewCounts() {
        return viewCounts;
    }

    public void setViewCounts(int viewCounts) {
        this.viewCounts = viewCounts;
    }

    public List<String> getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public void setViews(List<String> views) {
        this.views = views;
    }

    public void setPostVideos(List<PostVideo> postVideos) {
        this.postVideos = postVideos;
    }


    public boolean validate(){

        if(isEmpty()){

            return false;

        }

        return true;

    }

    @Exclude
    public boolean isEmpty(){

        if( (null == getTitle() || getTitle().isEmpty()) &&
                (null == getDescription() || getDescription().isEmpty()) &&
                (null == getPostImages() || getPostImages().isEmpty()) &&
                (null == getPostVideos() || getPostVideos().isEmpty())){

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    public void incrementViews(String currentUserId, String postId){

        this.setViewCounts(this.getViewCounts() + 1);
        this.getViews().add(currentUserId);

        LocalDataProvider.getInstance().viewPost(postId);


    }

    public boolean containsUnsavedObjects(){

        if(null != getPostImages() && !getPostImages().isEmpty()){

            for(PostImage postImage : getPostImages()){

                if(null != postImage && null == postImage.getId()) return true;

            }

        }

        if(null != getPostVideos() && !getPostVideos().isEmpty()){

            for(PostVideo postVideo : getPostVideos()){

                if(null == postVideo.getId()) return true;

            }

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

Any clue here?

Comment: I copied your code, created a stub `Post` class, and don't see the odd behavior.  Can you add your `Post` class to your question?  Have you test the `Post` class outside of a transaction to see if it works as expected in that context?

Comment: ok thanks @BobSnyder I have posted the ```Post``` class. I will also check if the issue is with the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be this method:

```
public List<String> getLikes() {
    if(null == likes) return new ArrayList<String>();
    return likes;
}
```

When `likes` is null, this will return an anonymous `ArrayList`.  Any updates to that list are are lost, i.e. they are not applied to the state of the `Post` instance.  You probably intended:

```
public List<String> getLikes() {
    if(null == likes) likes = new ArrayList<String>();
    return likes;
}
```

During your debugging, you may have suspected that something was odd about `getLikes()` and tried to fix it with this:

```
if(null == post.getLikes())
    post.setLikes(new ArrayList<String>());
```

But that is ineffective because `getLikes()` never returns null.

Comment: hmm :) Thanks a lot Bob Snyder! Because I am trying out firebase I just thought the issues was from the transactional code;